# Что означает оператор >>=?

Tags: c++, операторы

Что означает оператор `>>=`?

Comment: оператор побитового сдвига с присваиванием, по аналогии с +=, -= и т.п.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5bk6ya5x.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Оператор `>>=` относится к группе [составных](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1) операторов присваивания. Поведение выражения с составным оператором присваивания `E1 op= E2` [эквивалентно](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#7) выражению `E1 = E1 op E2`. С тем лишь исключением, что `E1` вычисляется только 1 раз.

Оператор `>>` [является](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#3) оператором побитового сдвига вправо. Может быть применим только к целочисленным аргументам (или `enum`). И если `E1` является беззнаковым типом или знаковым типом, но с положительным значением, то результат выражения `E1 >>= E2` есть целая часть от деления `E1` на 2 в степени `E2`. Т.е. каждый сдвиг на 1 бит вправо интерпретируется как деление числа на 2.

При этом, если тип `E1` знаковый, а значение отрицательное - результат такого сдвига является зависимым от реализации. Хотя, скорее всего, тоже будет интерпретирован как арифметический (т.е. знаковый бит останется на своём месте). Однако, полагаться на это можно только при соответствующем упоминании в документации на  компилятор.

Answer (score 0):

`>>=` деление на 2

```
a = a >> 3;
```

тоже самое в короткой форме

```
a >>= 3;
```

деление на 2 в степени 3, то есть на 8.

Comment: Сдвиг вправо это не всегда деление на степень двойки. Точно так же как сдвиг влево не то же самое, что умножение на 2^n.

Answer (score 0):

Это побитовый сдвиг вправо. Если сдвигаем число - оно делится на два в степени.

Answer (score -1):

**<<=** *побитовый сдвиг влево* 
**>>=** *побитовый сдвиг вправо* 
Подробное описание [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B2_C_%D0%B8_C%2B%2B)